# Need help in calling my VB6 DLL

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6

I have some vb6 dll created and registered on my system and i want to call those dll from my VB.NET cod, where the parameters are supplied to the DLL and the response is gotten back. I have been on it since last week, done so much and still cant get a way through....I need help.

When i try calling the dll, i get the following response :
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E20D61AC-CEDA-4ECC-873C-0B9E14B90C16} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I would appreciate what to do to make this work.

Comment: Have you registered the VB6 dll on that machine with regsvr32?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My vb.net code can not Call my VB6 DLL when deployed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614078/my-vb-net-code-can-not-call-my-vb6-dll-when-deployed). This may also apply: [Using vb6 dll in .net desktop application on 64 bit windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9313558).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have compiled the vb.net project for x86 CPU (under project properties, compile, advanced properties). Also, make sure you have registered the dll using regsvr32. Either of these will cause this error, I believe.